Why does an R Shiny Datatable lose changes between cell edits?
Given the following code:
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Test Page"),
                DTOutput("strings"))

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  string_data <- data.frame(
    Name = c("ALICE", "BOB", "CHARLIE", "STEVE", "JENNIFER"),
    City = c("New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Cincinnati", "Cleveland"),
    Occupation = c("Engineer", "Artist", "Doctor", "Lawyer", "Accountant")
  )
  
  table_data <- reactiveVal(string_data)
  temp_table <- tibble(string_data)
  
  # Render the table
  output$strings <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      table_data(),
      editable = TRUE,
      options = list(
        pageLength = 5
      )
    )
  })
  
  data_proxy <- dataTableProxy("strings")
  
  # Observe cell edits
  observeEvent(input$strings_cell_edit, {
    new_edit <- input$strings_cell_edit
    commit_edits <- FALSE
    
    if (!is.null(new_edit)) {
      if (new_edit$col == 1) {
        check_me <- feat_name_val(new_edit$value, string_data)
        if (check_me == TRUE) {
          commit_edits = TRUE
        }
      }
      
      if (commit_edits == TRUE) {
        # Update the temp_table with the new value
        temp_table[new_edit$row, new_edit$col] <- new_edit$value
        
        print("debug")
        
      } else if (commit_edits == FALSE) {
        replaceData(data_proxy, temp_table, resetPaging = FALSE)
        reloadData(data_proxy)
        new_edit <- NULL
        #popup_message(check_return)
      }
      
    }
    
  })
  
}

feat_name_val = function(name,source_df) {
  acceptable_characters = list("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
                               "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
                               "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "_", "0", "1", "2",
                               "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
  name_split = strsplit(name, "")[[1]]
  dupl_check = name %in% source_df$Name
  true_check = "TRUE" %in% dupl_check
  
  if (length(name_split) > 27) {
    return ('This field must be 27 characters or less')
  }
  if (length(name_split) <= 0) {
    return ('This is a required field')
  }
  if (true_check == "TRUE") {
    return('This name is already being used.')
  }
  count = 0
  for (char in name_split) {
    if (char %in% acceptable_characters) {
      count = count + 1
    }
  }
  if (length(name_split) == count) {
    return (TRUE)
  } else {
    return ('This field can only contain capitalized alphanumeric characters separated by underscores')
  }
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

If I double click in a cell to edit it with a valid value (all caps), and then click out of the cell, I can see that the edited value is stored properly in temp_table.
If I then double click a different cell and make a valid edit to it, once I click out of the cell to "commit" the edit, temp_table will drop the previous edit and only store the most recently edited cell.
The actual app UI will still show the edited cell, but behind the scenes the edited value in temp_table gets dropped.
The goal here is to have a table that tracks all edited cells so that if an INvalid edit is made, I can reload the table using the following lines:
replaceData(data_proxy, temp_table, resetPaging = FALSE)
reloadData(data_proxy)

So that the invalid entry is dumped visually, but the valid entries are preserved.
I tried the following line of code:
temp_table[new_edit$row, new_edit$col] <- new_edit$value

The idea is that each time a cell is edited the change is written off to a temporary table which acts as a buffer so that if I need to do a reload, I can preserve the edits.
However in the debugger if I breakpoint the line after this one, I can see that on the second or third edit, the previous edits are no longer present in this table, despite it not being reinitialized. Is there some kind of behavior of DT that I'm not understanding here?

This is expected behavior and has nothing to do with DT. You are using temp_table[new_edit$row, new_edit$col] <- new_edit$value which alters temp_table only locally inside the observeEvent. Instead you would need to use <<- here which will modify temp_table globally.

This was indeed the solution. Apparently I still have much to learn about scoping in R. Thank you for your help @Jan - can you post this as an answer so that I can mark this as solved?

You are welcome. I rather would not write an answer here because it falls under the category "Caused by a typo" or alternatively e.g. this question could be used as a duplicate.

I wouldn't consider this "caused by a typo" even though the fix is a single character. The cause is the lack of knowledge that the expression in observe()/observeEvent() is transformed into a function with its own scope, making the <<- assignment necessary. @Illuminerdi this particular example doesn't really offer any insight into scoping in R in general. This is more an example of non-standard evaluation causing surprising results, as instead of the expression in the observer being evaluated it's captured and transformed into a function.
